# Covariant derivative of a covariant derivative

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, differentiation

I'm trying to find the covariant derivative of a covariant derivative, i.e. $\nabla_a (\nabla_b V_c)$.

This is something I've taken for granted a lot in calculations, namely I though that by the Leibniz rule we just have:

$$\nabla_a (\nabla_b V_c) = \partial_a(\nabla_b V_c) - \Gamma_{ab}^{d}\nabla_c V_d - \Gamma_{ac}^{d} \nabla_d V_c$$

However when we prove that the covariant derivative of a $(0,2)$ tensor is the above, we use the fact that the covariant derivative satisfies a Leibniz rule on $(0,1)$ tensors: $\nabla_a(w_b v_c) = v_c\nabla_a(w_b) + w_b\nabla_a(v_c)$. However $\nabla_a$ on it's own is not a tensor so how do we have the above formula for it's covariant derivative?

Comment: $\nabla_bV_c$ is a tensor, call it $A_{bc}$. Then how do you find $\nabla_aA_{bc}$?

Comment: By using the Leibniz rule? Which to prove we needed to use the fact that $A_{bc}$ splits into (0,1) tensors.

Comment: Why is that a problem?

Comment: Well $A_{bc}$ doesn't split into two (0,1) tensors, because $\nabla_b$ is not a tensor? I may well be being very stupid and missing something here!

Comment: @Wooster You don't need to split $A_{bc}$ into two $(0,1)$ tensors. Hint: what is $\nabla_a (V^b A_{bc})$ for some arbitrary vector $V^b$?

Comment: $\nabla V$ splits as $\sum_{ij}V^i{}_{;j}\partial_i\otimes\mathrm{d}x^j$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Easy way**
Let me first state the straight-forward way to do this computation.
$$
\langle \nabla_a \nabla_b V, \partial_c\rangle =
\partial_a \langle \nabla_b V, \partial_c \rangle - \langle \nabla_aV, \nabla_a \partial_c\rangle = \partial_a (\nabla_bV)_c - (\nabla_bV)_d \Gamma_{ac}^d
$$

First equality follows from compatibility, second equality uses definition of Levi-Civita symbols.

**Hard way**
You are suggesting a roundabout way to do this, which formalizes to the following: 
$$
\nabla_a\nabla_bV = \nabla_a\left[~(\nabla_cV\otimes dx^c)[\partial_b]~\right]
= \nabla_a\left[~C(\nabla_cV\otimes dx^c \otimes \partial_b)~\right]
= C [\nabla_a (\nabla_cV\otimes dx^c \otimes \partial_b)]
$$

where $$
C: T_pM \otimes T_pM \otimes T^*_pM \to T_pM, ~~ w\otimes z\otimes V \to
z[V]w
$$

is the contraction map of the last two arguments. Covariant derivative on mixed-type tensors commute with contractions (used in the last equality). Observe the expression within $C[ \cdots ]$ is a covariant derivative of a mixed tensor, which you can compute with the Leibneiz rule, and use your favorite component-wise formulas.

Answer (score 3):

The term $\nabla_b V_c$ is a (0,2) tensor writing in the abstract index notation,  when writing in full basis form it reads
\begin{equation} 
\nabla_b V_c \;dx^b\otimes dx^c\;,
\end{equation}
Now the status of $\nabla_b V_c $ is a components it *is a **scalar** function* while $dx^b\otimes dx^c$ is a basis of (0,2)-tensor.

Then the double covariant derivative reads
\begin{equation} 
\nabla \Big(  \nabla_b V_c \;dx^b\otimes dx^c  \Big)\;, 
\end{equation}
where $$\nabla_b V_c \equiv \partial_b V_c -\Gamma_b{}^q{}_c V_q\;.$$
The **Leibniz rule** is needed in this step
\begin{eqnarray}
\nabla \Big(  \nabla_b V_c \;dx^b\otimes dx^c  \Big)&=& \nabla \Big(  \nabla_b V_c \Big)\;dx^b\otimes dx^c  + \nabla_b V_c \;\nabla \Big( dx^b \Big)\otimes dx^c + \nabla_b V_c \;dx^b\otimes \nabla \Big( dx^c  \Big)\;,\\
&=& \nabla_m \Big( \overbrace{ \nabla_b V_c}^{a\; scalar} \Big)\;dx^m\otimes dx^b\otimes dx^c  + \nabla_b V_c \;\times \Big(-\Gamma^b{}_n dx^n \Big)\otimes dx^c \\&&+ \nabla_b V_c \;dx^b\otimes  \times \Big( -\Gamma^c{}_p dx^p \Big)\;,\\
&=& \nabla_m \Big( \overbrace{ \nabla_b V_c}^{a\; scalar} \Big)\;dx^m\otimes dx^b\otimes dx^c  -\Gamma^b{}_n \nabla_b V_c \;  dx^n \otimes dx^c \\&& -\Gamma^c{}_p \nabla_b V_c \;dx^b\otimes   dx^p \;,\\
&=&\partial_m \Big( \overbrace{ \nabla_b V_c}^{a\; scalar} \Big)\;dx^m\otimes dx^b\otimes dx^c  -\Gamma_r{}^b{}_n dx^{r} \otimes \nabla_b V_c \; dx^{n} \otimes dx^c \\&&-\Gamma_s{}^c{}_p dx^{s} \otimes \nabla_b V_c \;dx^b  \otimes dx^{p} \;,\\
&=&\partial_m \Big(  \nabla_b V_c \Big)\;dx^m\otimes dx^b\otimes dx^c  - \Gamma_r{}^b{}_n\nabla_b V_c \;  dx^r \otimes dx^n \otimes dx^c \\&&-\Gamma_s{}^c{}_p \nabla_b V_c \;dx^s\otimes   dx^b\otimes dx^p \;,\\
&=&\Big[\partial_m \Big(  \nabla_b V_c \Big)- \Gamma_m{}^d{}_b\nabla_d V_c-\Gamma_m{}^e{}_c \nabla_b V_e\Big ]\;dx^m\otimes dx^b\otimes dx^c \;.
\end{eqnarray}
Then we define
$$
\nabla \Big(  \nabla_b V_c \;dx^b\otimes dx^c  \Big)=:\nabla_m \nabla_b V_c \;dx^m \otimes dx^b\otimes dx^c
$$
Finally, in abstract index notation we have
$$
\nabla_m \nabla_b V_c \equiv \partial_m \Big(  \nabla_b V_c \Big)- \Gamma_m{}^d{}_b\nabla_d V_c-\Gamma_m{}^e{}_c \nabla_b V_e
$$