# Second covariant derivative product rule

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, differentiation

I am tasked with doing the following problem

$$\nabla_a\nabla_b(T^{ij}G_{vk}).$$ This is a tensor product of one (2,0) and one (0,2) rank tensor. I know how to take the second covariant derivative of a single tensor but not a product. Since I'm taking a second covariant derivative, does it obey the Leibniz rule: $$\nabla_b(T^{ij}G_{vk})=G_{vk}\nabla_bT^{ij}+T^{ij}\nabla_bG_{vk}=G_{vk}(\partial_bT^{ij}+\Gamma^i_{bm}T^{mj}+\Gamma^j_{mb}T^{im})+T^{ij}(\partial_bG_{vk}-\Gamma^l_{bv}G_{lk}-\Gamma^l_{bk}G_{vl}),$$ or is there a different Leibniz rule I must use? If there is, is there a formula for taking the covariant derivative of two arbitrary tensors?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Covariant derivative of a covariant derivative](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/256393/)

Comment: sort of so the leibniz rule does hold? So this would be right? $$\nabla_a\nabla_b(T^{ij}G_{vk})=\nabla_bT^{ij}\nabla_aG_{vk}+\nabla_a\nabla_bT^{ij}G_{vk}$$??

Comment: There's nothing special about two tensors. When you take the covariant derivative you just treat it as a single tensor $T^{ij} G_{vk} = A^{ij}_{\;\;\, vk}$. So your double covariant derivative will have $6\times 5 =30$ terms.

Comment: So I just take the second covariant derivative $$\nabla_a\nabla_bA^{ij}_{vk}$$ normally with the connection coefficients and all?

Comment: Yes. A tensor product of two tensors is again a tensor. Do remember to order the indices properly. Notation such as $A^{ij}_{vk}$ is ambiguous.

Comment: So I'll get the same answer if I take the tensor product or if I use product rule?